# Get rid of automatic ease in and out

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am trying to make an object move from one side of the screen to the other at a steady pace. Whenever I use the following line of code, the object slowly begins to move, then goes at its fastest speed when it is halfway across the screen, and finally slows down until it reaches the other side of the screen. In other words it is doing an ease-in and ease-out. Here is the code I am using.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{ circle.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);}];
```

Any ideas on how to get the object to move at a steady pace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

with UIViewAnimationCurveLinear as options parameter.